# Ethernet card gets recognized randomly

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I'm running a netinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. During installation, I have only selected to install a basic OpenSSH server, and nothing else. I'm currently trying to install other packages (window and display managers, browser, everything else) by hand. However, I've encountered a problem:

Sometimes, when I boot my computer, Ubuntu won't recognize my ethernet card at all. It's like it didn't even try. I get this error when trying to `ifconfig up`:

**ifconfig p4p1 up**

```
p4p1: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Here is some information when it works (and when it works, it *just works*, everything goes smoothly):

**lspci -nnk | grep iA2 Ethernet**

```
        04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:04c1]
        Kernel driver in use: r8101
```

**Note**: the kernel driver is a driver I got from Realtek's website, compiled myself and added to the `/etc/modules` file. I then blacklisted the old driver (which was r8169) in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. This was an attempt to fix the problem, as it also happened with the old driver.

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
    logical name: p4p1
    version: 05
    serial: 84:8f:69:b5:e6:d0
    size: 100Mbit/s
    capacity: 100Mbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8101 
driverversion=1.027.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.210 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
    resources: irq:30 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0404000-e0404fff memory:e0400000-e0403fff
```

**Note**: I do have NetworkManager installed, but this was happening even before installing NetworkManager. I believe the problem is not related to it. Before installing NetworkManager, I also tried removing every line in `/etc/network/interfaces` except for the loopback entry. Sometimes things worked when I did an `ifconfig p4p1 up` followed by `dhclient`, sometimes it didn't.

When things don't work, the interface just disappears. I don't get output from `lshw` or `lspci`. Whenever things don't work, I have also tried to `dmesg | grep "0000:04:00"` to check if any error related to the bus appeared, however **there is not a single output line**. I even did a `dmesg | grep pci` and went through all logs to see if I could find something, but nothing.

**VERY IMPORTANT**: I have just found that this problem happens in an even/odd manner: whenever boot T fails, boot T+1 works, and boot T+2 fails again. All it takes is to boot, check that the interface is not up (through `ifconfig`) and then reboot. In the next boot, it works. Magically.

Do you have any ideas? I can provide more info if needed.